# Why does setting const char* gives segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have this simple function

```
 struct MyException : public exception
{
    const char *errorMessage = NULL;

    void SetMessage(const char* message)
    {
        errorMessage = message;
    }

  const char * what () const throw ()
  {
    return errorMessage;
  }
};
struct MyException *socketException;
```

and when I call

```
socketException->SetMessage("socket connection error");
       throw *socketException;
```

I get segmentation fault right at the line where I set message to errorMessage. I am missing something very fundamental but I couldn't figure it out. I checked other questions about segmentation fault and I know it is sometimes about misusage of pointers. But I still do not get that.

Comment: You're doing something else, something that you do not show us, to cause the crash.

Comment: This code [works](http://rextester.com/WMIY66402). The problem must needs lie somewhere in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN No, the OP attempts to reassign a pointer (which initially points to `NULL`) to point somewhere else.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I edited the question.

Comment: `socketException` is an uninitialized pointer, pointing to some random garbage. Calling a method on such a pointer exhibits undefined behavior. The whole `errorMessage` dance is a red herring.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I said I might me missing something fundamental. Thank you very much.

Comment: The `public exception` part looks like you used `using namespace std` at global scope in a header file. That's very bad practice.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Or it's a null-pointer, if declared in the global scope, still UB though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never create an instance of class `MyException`, so when you try to call `SetMessage`, you have no object on which to call it.

Do this instead:

```
struct MyException socketException;

...

socketException.SetMessage("socket connection error");
       throw socketException;
```